# Linking libiconv on ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker, iconv

I am trying to use the objective-git library for an ios application I am in the proccess of developing. I am able to get the library to compile, link, and run perfectly fine in the simulator. However, when I try to run the application on an actual iPad, I get the followign error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_libiconv", referenced from:
      _git_path_iconv in libObjectiveGit-iOS.a(path.c.o)
  "_libiconv_close", referenced from:
      _git_path_iconv_clear in libObjectiveGit-iOS.a(path.c.o)
  "_libiconv_open", referenced from:
      _git_path_iconv_init_precompose in libObjectiveGit-iOS.a(path.c.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I believe the issue is that I am compiling the libgit2 library with a different version of iconv then the one included with ios. However, I have messed with the build script in an attempt to force it to link with the ios version, but the error persists. How should I go about properly linking the iconv library so that I can run the application on an actual device?

Comment: Set your architecture as "armv7", remove "armv7s"

Comment: I already tried that. It works fine for i386 and x86_64, but not arm7, arm7s, or arm64.

Comment: Well, Xcode 5.0.2 was just released and it fixed the problem. Go figure.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `libiconv.tbd` to 'Link Binary With Libraries' section in Build Phases.

Note: I know `ObjectiveGit` fixed this issue but maybe that helps to others those who are trying to use iconv in their projects.